# The post request in nodejs return nothing for passport authentication

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

Am a newbie to Node.js, Am getting only a loading page in node.js post request when running the passport authentication. Can anyone help me

> my Router.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var User = require('../models/user-model');
var Local = require('../config/passport-local');


/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next){
  res.render('index',{ title : 'Login'});
});

router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('local',(req, res,next) => {
    console.log('ok');  
  });
}, (req, res, next) => {

});
module.exports = router;
```

> passport-local.js

```
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var User = require('../models/user-model')

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, next) {
        console.log('auth');
        User.findOne({username: username}, function(err, user) {
            console.log('passport');
            if(err) { return  next(err);}
            if(!user) { 
                return next(null, false, {message : 'invalid username'});
            }
            if(!user.validPassword(password)) {
                return next(null, false, {message: 'invalid password'})
            }
            return next(null, user);
        });
    }
));
```

> App.js

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var commonKeys = require('./config/keys');

var app = express();

//connect mongoDb 
mongoose.connect(commonKeys.mongoDB.connect + '/' + commonKeys.mongoDB.database, { useNewUrlParser: true });

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');


app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//app.use(flash());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

I am trying to learn passport authentication in nodejs. it is much appriciated if anyone can explain the error in this code and why its not working.

Comment: You are not returning anything from there... use `res.send`.

Comment: even my console is not giving output as `auth` which is in `console.log('auth')`. in the passport-local.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your code accordingly:

```
router.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local'),
  function(req, res) {
    // If this function gets called, authentication was successful.
    // `req.user` contains the authenticated user.
    res.send('Done');
  });
```

Here's more [documentation](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/downloads/html/).